# How to use VPN with group security and hardware token?

Tags: vpn

I was trying to use VPN with group security and hardware token, but could not find anything about it for OpenVPN or VPNC.

I have the setting under windows like:

[image]

How can I do this? Is there any tool that can help?

Comment: Maybe you could be more precise in your question by saying it's an avaya vpn